# User selected NSImage reload after app relaunch in Objective C for macOS

Tags: objective-c, macos, sandbox, nsimage, nsimageview

I am making a small project where a user can select an image and change it with filters.

I've got it working how I want, however I want all the user selected settings to return on relauch of the app. I've got all the filter settings to remain using plists.

But I can't find away of reloading the NSImage into the NSImageView after relaunch due to sandboxing - i've saved the user selected file path into a plist and have tried to load the Image in using the image URL however because of sandboxing it will not load it back.

Is there a special way I need to do this?

EDIT

Following advise to use a secure scoped bookmark i'm still having some issues

On my Awake nib I have written this - when I use NSLog on the path it is displaying the correct path but the image doesn't show in my image view.

```
 NSData *bookmark =[preferences objectForKey:@"bookmark"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:bookmark
                                             options:NSURLBookmarkResolutionWithSecurityScope
                                     relativeToURL:nil bookmarkDataIsStale:nil error:nil];
    NSString *path = url.absoluteString;
    NSImage* imgC = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
    imageView2.image = imgC;
```

In my NSOpenPanel I have written this, so you can see how I created the bookmark

```
NSData *bookmark = nil;
                        NSError *error = nil;
                        bookmark = [url bookmarkDataWithOptions:NSURLBookmarkCreationWithSecurityScope
                                 includingResourceValuesForKeys:nil
                                                  relativeToURL:nil // Make it app-scoped
                                                          error:&error];
                        if (error) {
                            NSLog(@"Error creating bookmark for URL (%@): %@", url, error);
                            [NSApp presentError:error];
                        }

                       // NSLog(@"bookmark: %@", bookmark);
                    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                    [userDefaults setObject:bookmark forKey:@"bookmark"];
```

Comment: You need a Security Scoped Bookmark to make access of the URL permanent or save the image in the container.

Comment: Thanks Vadian, for putting me on the right path, i've been writing some code for a security scoped bookmark following Apple Docs however while I can output the path correctly I can't seem to get the image loaded into an NSImageView - i've updated my answer - do you know where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Replace `url.absoluteString` with `url.path` or - better - use the URL related API `initWithContentsOfURL`.

Comment: I changed that, but still not loading anything else you can see which I may have done wrong?

Comment: Use `dataForKey` instead of `objectForKey`. And handle the error.

Comment: Hmm still not working i've tested using a file from bundle and it works fine displaying from bundle imageView2.image =[NSImage imageNamed:@"image"];

I've checked NSLogged the path and it's correct: /Users/Germ/Downloads/logo.png

So is there something wrong with this line: imageView2.image =[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url]; or is sandboxing still causing me an issue even with secure scope bookmarks?

I added this as boolean com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.document-scope set to 1 in my entitlements by the way.

Comment: A bookmark for the Downloads folder is not necessary. Set the entitlement. And again, don’t ignore errors by passing `nil`. Pass an NSError pointer and read the error.

Comment: It's a user selected file so it may not be Download folder a user could select an image from any folder. The entitlement is already set.

I've created an NSError and read it and this is what it says - not exactly helpful!
The operation could not be completed.
No other information is available about the problem.

Comment: I was outputting it wrong it came up with that error because the error was returnin nill i've fixed the error catching and there is no error - so I have no idea why it's not loading in the NSImageView

Comment: Figured it out forgot to do [url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource]; and [url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];